# C: Segfault when deleting first item in Doubly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

for class I'm to write a program which processes data and sorts it into separate lists.

So far, I created a list to hold the data, and then an array of list for each separate "customer" and their "books purchased".

I'm getting a segfault when trying to delete the first item from list.

```
Please enter the name of your input file.
input1.txt
Reading in: 'input1.txt'
5 10 1 407 2 8127 1 8131 4 22048 5 407 3 64 5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Just created 5 lists.
Customer ID: 1   BookID: 407
2 8127 1 8131 4 22048 5 407 3 64 5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 2   BookID: 8127
1 8131 4 22048 5 407 3 64 5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 1   BookID: 8131
4 22048 5 407 3 64 5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 4   BookID: 22048
5 407 3 64 5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 5   BookID: 407
3 64 5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 3   BookID: 64
5 22026 2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 5   BookID: 22026
2 19 1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 2   BookID: 19
1 406 3 162779
Customer ID: 1   BookID: 406
3 162779
Customer ID: 3   BookID: 162779
List is empty.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here's my code in main:

```
//  Create x amount of array with x being the first number in 'holder'.
ListHndl list[getFirst(holder)];
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= getFirst(holder); i++) {
    list[i] = newList();
}
printf("Just created %d lists.\n", getFirst(holder));


deleteFirst(holder); // Delete the # of customers
deleteFirst(holder); // Delete the # of purchases

//  Iterate and process 'holder'.
long customer, bookID;
while (!isEmpty(holder)) {
    customer = getFirst(holder);
    deleteFirst(holder);
    bookID = getFirst(holder);
    deleteFirst(holder);
    printf("Customer ID: %d\t BookID: %d\n",customer, bookID);
    // insertOrder(list[customer], bookID);
    printList(NULL, holder);
}
```

Here's part of list.h:

```
typedef struct NodeStruct {
        long data;
        struct NodeStruct* next;
        struct NodeStruct* prev;
} NodeStruct;

//      Rename NodeStruct* as NodePtr
typedef NodeStruct* NodePtr;

typedef struct ListStruct {
        NodePtr first;
        NodePtr last;
        NodePtr current;
} ListStruct;

//      ListHndl is just a ListStruct* renamed.
```

Here's the deleteFirst function:

```
void deleteFirst(ListHndl L) {
        assert (!isEmpty(L));
        NodePtr tmp = L->first;
        if(L->first->next == NULL)
            L->last = NULL;
        else L->first->next->prev = NULL;
        L->first = L->first->next;
        free(tmp);

}
```

Here's the insertSort function.

```
void insertOrder(ListHndl L, long data) {

        NodePtr tmp = newNode();
    tmp->data = data;

    NodePtr prev = NULL;
    NodePtr curr = L->first;

    while (curr != NULL && data > curr->data) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL) L->last = tmp;
    if (prev == NULL) L->first = tmp;
    else prev->next = tmp;
    tmp->next = curr;

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.
And this is what valgrind shows:

```
==498== Invalid read of size 8
==498==    at 0x400D41: getFirst (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x400AA1: main (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==498==
==498==
==498== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==498==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==498==    at 0x400D41: getFirst (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x400AA1: main (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==498==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==498==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==498==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==498==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==498==
==498== HEAP SUMMARY:
==498==     in use at exit: 952 bytes in 17 blocks
==498==   total heap usage: 39 allocs, 22 frees, 1,480 bytes allocated
==498==
==498== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==498==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==498==    by 0x400B81: newList (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x400958: main (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==
==498== 120 bytes in 5 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==498==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==498==    by 0x400B81: newList (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x400A34: main (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==
==498== 240 bytes in 10 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==498==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==498==    by 0x400C0C: newNode (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x40111C: insertOrder (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x400B02: main (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==
==498== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==498==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==498==    by 0x35CF8671CA: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==498==    by 0x4008E8: openFile (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==    by 0x40094A: main (in /afs/cats.ucsc.edu/users/m/rho5/private/cmps101/program2/store)
==498==
==498== LEAK SUMMARY:
==498==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==498==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==498==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==498==    still reachable: 952 bytes in 17 blocks
==498==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==498==
==498== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==498== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
make: *** [valgrind] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT: I believe the problem occurs when trying to delete the First element when there is only ONE element left in the list.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? Also, this isn't all of the code - the problem could easily be in one of the functions you haven't shown. See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Your ListHndl is a pointer? How is it being passed to insertOrder? Can you verify by say writing a print function that at least 2 -3 inserts were done correctly? The question / code is quite abstract so hard to guess problem lies in above code or not.

Comment: @fayyazkl , sorry. Code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

when you delete the first element of a list containing at least 2 elements, you delete the first element of the list in the else branch:

```
L->first->next->prev = NULL;
```

thereafter, you reference the `NULL`ed pointer wit the instruction

```
L->first = L->first->next;
```

instead, you should write

```
L->first = tmp->next;
```

note:
this analysis assumes that in your linked list implementation, `x->next->prev == x`.

Comment: I updated it to what you suggested, same error still.